# How to modify the default Check-in Action in TFS?

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfs-workitem

The default check-in action for a work-item is "resolve". I'd like to set it to "associate" so that this work item isn't automaticaly closed if I check-in stuff too fast. How can I do that?

Comment: It's possible to change the default in registry-see answer  in similar [VS2008 TFS: Is it possible to change the default Check-in Action for work items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3273873/52277).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, the check-in action can only be associated to a state transition (i.e. Active to Resolved).  In my blog post that [Fredrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294/how-to-modify-the-defaul-check-in-action-in-tfs#62376) linked to (http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/top_tfs_tip_3_r.html) I talk about how to remove that.  You'll need to customize the work item for everyone in your team project to make this happen.  For help on that see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243849(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Martin Woodward blogged about how to *remove* the "Resolve" action from the check-in dialog as a work-around for this:

http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/top_tfs_tip_3_r.html

Answer (score 3):

For newer versions of Visual Studio, you can now set this default in the UI:

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server -> (Uncheck) Resolve associated work items on check-in

Answer (score 0):

Unlike previous versions, in VS2015 the registry key solution seems to work in the cases we need!

I just went to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior
```

and changed `ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction` from `True` to `False`.