# VS2008 TFS: Is it possible to change the default Check-in Action for work items?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs

When I check in code to our Team Foundation Server, I some times (probably more often than I actually do...) should associate my check-in with a task or a bug I am working towards. When I mark a task or a check in, it sets the Check-in Action to Resolve. But almost always, I just want to have it as just Associate. The result is that I often end up marking a task as resolved by mistake. Is there a way to make Associate the default when I mark a task?

Resolving a bug or a task should be something I actively select. Like, this work item is related to my check-in AND it is now resolved. Not, this work item is related to my check-in, and btw, I still haven't fixed it completely yet...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify the defaul Check-in Action in TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294/how-to-modify-the-defaul-check-in-action-in-tfs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way to make resolve and associate both available but default to associate.  Therefore the safest option for you is probably to remove the check-in action altogether and remember to update the work item when you have finished associating things with it.  For more information see the following blog post I wrote a while ago.

[TFS Top Tip #3: Removing the Resolve Check-In Action from a Work Item](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/top_tfs_tip_3_r.html)

Comment: ok. but seems like this have to be done for every work item, and that it will affect everyone? if so I guess I will just have to live with it. Thanks anyways =)

Answer (score 5):

TFS **2010** doesn't have UI to change the default Check-in Action for work items.
I've raised a suggestion in [MS Connect](https://www.bing.com/?ref=aka&shorturl=connect-redirect)

However see post
[How To: Make “Associate” the default action for work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mitrik/how-to-make-associate-the-default-action-for-work-items)

> To make “Associate” the default action
> (instead of “Resolve”), set the
> registry key
> “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior\ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction”
> to “False”.

Comment: 1. Not an answer. 2. No idea :p