# Can I modify the default Check-in Action in TFS 2010?

Tags: workitem, checkin

When you associate a changeset with a workitem TFS defaults to resolving the workitem.  I want to default to associating it.

I know in TFS **2008** you had to remove resolve check-in action using something like this http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/000230.html but I thought that I read somewhere that there was a better way to do this in TFS **2010**.  Does anyone know whether this is the case?

TIA,
Bill

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294/how-to-modify-the-defaul-check-in-action-in-tfs

Answer (score 31):

With Visual Studio 2010 you can achive this very easy:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior 
@ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction = "False"

Comment: Just want to point out that this isn't "very easy". Sure it is once someone comes up with the cryptic registry changes but why does something this simple have to be a registry change? The default action should be "Associate" and not "Resolve". That's the convention in other source control system. And rare is the work item that is resolved with a single check-in (at least in my experience).

Comment: BTW, I voted up your comment because it worked :) Just don't agree with the "very easy" designation.

Comment: Thanks! BTW... I've been messing with the registry since 1997. So IMHO it should be considered "very easy" by now, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Tundey not sure it's 'rare' that a checkin = a Work Item. It's totally subjective sure, but I find it's more like 50/50. Maybe you're not decomposing your tasks sufficiently?

Comment: I guess it depends. If you check in each file individually (perhaps because you want the comments to be as specific as possible) then you'll find yourself having more than 1 check-in per work item. At least that's been my experience.